# Some find of overflow issue with this code. small number is extremely negative

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, overflow, undefined-behavior

Here is my code, trying to make an array of ten numbers and output the largest and smallest of the bunch. When i run this my smaller is a very large negative number:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nums[10];
    int small, large;
    large = small = nums[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter an integer number:" << endl;
        cin >> nums[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (large < nums[i])
            large = nums[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (small > nums[i])
            small = nums[i];
    }

    cout << "The biggest number entered was " << large << ". " << endl;
    cout << "While the smallerst number entered was " << small << ". " << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get an error : system was not declared in this score : system("pause");

Comment: oh ok thank you I just initialized large and small inside of their respective loops and that seems to have solved the problem thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are reading from an uninitialized variable here:

```
if (large < nums[i]) // large has not been initialized here
```

and here

```
if (small > nums[i]) // small has not been initialized here
```

This is undefined behaviour.

Technically, you have assigned a value to both of them. But that value itself comes from an uninitialized variable:

```
large = small = nums[0]; // nums has not been initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

`num[0]` here:

```
large = small = nums[0];
                ^^^^^^^
```

has an indeterminate value since it was not initialized, so both `large` and `small` will also have indeterminate values after this assignment. Using indeterminate values like you do here:

```
if (small > nums[i])
```

is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and can have any result.

Answer (score 0):

The only bug was to assign small and large before you had values in the array num[]. 
I've edited your code and it works as (I think) you intend it.

```
#include <iostream>
```

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nums[10];
    int small, large;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter an integer number:" << endl;
    cin >> nums[i];
}
large = small = nums[0];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (large < nums[i])
        large = nums[i];
    if (small > nums[i])
        small = nums[i];
}

cout << "The biggest number entered was " << large << ". " << endl;
cout << "While the smallerst number entered was " << small << ". " << endl;
//system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Changes:
fixed the bug with uninitialized large and small;
removed extra for loop (you don't need it)
removed system("pause") because it caused error compiling on my machine and I don't see the need for it here.